# Tensor placeholder changes name on re-instantiation in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have not been able to find anything on this issue.

I am attempting to train a network repeatedly while varying hyper parameters in order to do something like what is shown in this video: https://youtu.be/eBbEDRsCmv4?t=870 (where he is showing a hyper parameter search by repeatedly running a network with varying hyper parameters)

However, I encounter an error because each time the placeholder variables are instantiated they change names, leading to the error

> "InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor 'input/x-input' with dtype float and shape
>   [?,784]    [[Node: input/x-input = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT,
>   shape=[?,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]"

I traced this down to a renaming of the "input" placeholder.  When the loop (shown in the code below) runs the placeholder is named first "input/x-input:0" and second "input_1/x-input:0".  I believe my error is caused by this renaming, but I am not sure how to correct it.

The following code is the smallest portion I could write that reproduces my issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def train():

  # Input placeholders
  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x-input')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y-input')

  return x

def main(_):
    for i in range(2):
        x = train()
        print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main=main)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by adding the line:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```